# p tag within a div affecting the adjacent div's position

Tags: html, css

```css
.navi { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red; 
} 

.navi-item { 
  width: 50px; 
  height: inherit; 
  background: blue; 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 10px; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <div class="navi-item">
    <div>logo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navi-item">`enter code here`
    <p class="p-tag">Home</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The logo div gets pushed down when p-tag is added.
But when  tag in place of

tag is doing fine.

Comment: But when <a> tag in place of <p> tag is doing fine

Comment: can you provide the CSS as well?

Comment: Maybe this will help `.navi-item p.p-tag { margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0; line-height: 1; }` Possibly only margin: 0 is enough, that's sometihing you can try.

Comment: .navi {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
  }

  .navi-item {
   width: 50px;
   height: inherit;
   background: blue;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 10px;
  }

Comment: click on edit under your Question post to add this ;)

Comment: @Mahesh Guduru Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: bron your solution works with margin and padding set to 0 but,same problems comes up when margin or padding is added to p tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements such as paragraph have default css values that might have an effect on some elements.
In this case p has following css from browser -

- clear: both
- margin-bottom: 1em

in this case i would suggest you try to add `<span>` instead of `<p>` and see if there will be any change.
From your code example, it looks like 'Home' will be a link anyway, where you would use `<a>` not `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `display: flex` in `.navi`

```css
.navi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex; /*add*/
}

.navi-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: inherit;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <div class="navi-item">
    <div>logo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navi-item">`enter code here`
    <p class="p-tag">Home</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's works, can you tell me the reason behind it

Comment: youre welcome. So Flexbox’s underlying principle is to make layouts flexible and intuitive. To accomplish this, it lets containers decide for themselves how to evenly distribute their children — including their size and the space between them. But if Flexbox is new for you, I invite you to read this article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35/ for instance.